# Во что компилируется контроллер?

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Допустим, я сделал правки только в контроллере и не хочу по новой разворачивать сайт. Куда компилируется контроллер и можно ли обновить только его?

Comment: веб приложение собирается в дллку

Comment: И какое название она носит? По названию проекта?

Comment: обычно да, название проекта

Comment: И чем же, по-вашему, контроллер отличается от любого другого класса в приложении?

Answer (score 1):

Изменения на ходу в проект можно вносить только во View (HTML-разметку).
В остальных случаях (классы и, соответственно, сами контроллеры) необходимо будет пересобрать проект и развернуть сайт заново.